# Chaining the ++ operator

Tags: c++

I noticed in C++ that something like`++++i` is allowed and increments `i` by 2. However, `i++++` is not allowed. Why is the latter not allowed whereas the former is?

Comment: i++ returns the current value of i and then increases i by 1. doing i++++ is going to do what?

Comment: Note that the first is undefined behaviour until C++11.

Comment: Note also that `++++i` is illegal in C.

Comment: Re *Note that the first is undefined behaviour until C++11.* -- Should of stayed that way.

Comment: [Maybe using paranthesis to separate them](http://ideone.com/pm9h5S). Also if one wants to use multiple "++" why not to just use "+= the_amount_we_want_it"

Comment: The real question is why you are contemplating such code. These operators are very dangerous.

Comment: @Gasim: Adding parenthesis doesn't help. The expression inside the parens is still not a modifiable l-value. The code in your link is performing pre-increment twice, which has already been established as legal, even without parens.

Comment: @DavidHammen I know you're half joking, but I disagree. The new rules are way saner.

Comment: @sftrabbit, Out of curiosity, is that just in relation to the prefix increment operator, or are there other specific sequencing changes that you find better?

Comment: @chris Just the new sequencing rules in general. It seems nicer to me to have sequencing relationships within expression where they make sense. The previous sequence points stuff was just a bit lazy.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Half joking? No. I would much rather that this had been made illegal rather than giving it defined behavior. I would take someone to the cleaner if I saw `++++i` in a code review.

Comment: @DavidHammen I'm not saying you should do it. I'm just saying the sequencing rules make more sense.

Comment: @sftrabbit: True, but that's not saying much. Anything makes more sense than undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of postfix `++` is a prvalue. Postfix `++` can only be applied to modifiable lvalue. So you can't apply postfix `++` to the result of another postfix `++`. This makes sense because it needs some object to modify. The result of the operator is just a value (a copy of the original value of the operand) - there's no object for you to modify.

On the other hand, the result of prefix `++` is an lvalue and it also expects an lvalue as its operand. Therefore you can pass the result of a prefix `++` to another `++`.

It might help for you to think about lvalues as denoting objects in memory and rvalues as just values (that may have come from an object in memory). Postfix `++` expects an lvalue because it wants an object that it can modify. It returns an rvalue because the result is just a value not associated with any object (because it was copied from the operand before modification). Prefix `++` also wants to modify its operand, so also expects an lvalue. However, it returns the object *after* modification, which is the operand object itself and so its result is an lvalue too.

Comment: Is there any reason why the postfix++ was not written to return a modifiable value?

Comment: @user2612743, How can it? It has to return the old value, and the variable has to be incremented.

Comment: Yes, it creates a copy of the object, because it returns the object in its old state.

`int i=0;std::cout << i++;` would print 0, but after this line i is 1.

Comment: @user2612743 Let me know if my further explanations make any sense.